# React update css panel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an app that moves and splits panels.  When you are on the border of a panel you can split it by holding ctrl on the border or move it. I have panels 1 , 2, 3, 4 and a chooser. Right now I have a button on the chooser panel and you can select 1 , 2, 3 or 4. Right now it just throws an alert. What would be the best way to have the chooser panel be able to select panel 1 , 2, 3 or 4.

```js
    import {useState} from 'react';
    
    const BlenderSplitter = ( {children, layout} ) => {
    
        // useState for the layout.  This represents how sub-panes are divided and
        // whatnot
        const [layoutState, setLayoutState] = useState(layout);
    
        // Used to lookup child by name
        const childMap = {};
        children.forEach( e => childMap[ e.props.id ] = e );
    
        // Each state has a StateEnum called "stateEnum" along with whatever
        // data is needed for that state.  The following are the possible values
        // for the enum.
        const StateEnum = {
            None: "None",
            ElgibleToMove: "ElgibleToMove", // The cursor is over a split which is eligible to move
            AboutToMove: "AboutToMove",     // User pressed mouse button and is about to drag
            Moving: "Moving",               // User is dragging with mouse pressed
            ElgibleToCopy: "ElgibleToCopy", // Cursor is over a split and ctrl is pressed
            AboutToCopy: "AboutToCopy",     // User has pressed mouse button with ctrl and is about to drag
        }
    
        // useState for storing state information
        const [state, setState] = useState( { //Initial state set to "none"
            stateEnum: StateEnum.None,
        } );
    
        // Function for converting from pixels to percent (within this container).
        // Everything within this component is in a percent coordinate system
        const eventToPercentVector = e => {
            const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: (e.clientX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left) * 100,
                y: (e.clientY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top) * 100 };
        }
    
        // The margin that is close enough to a split to be considered "on" the split.
        // This is within percent (not pixels).
        const reshapeMargin = 1;
    
        // Function that finds the nearest split(s) to a given vector (mouse pointer location).  This 
        // method returns an array of arrays.  The outer array is the number of "matches" and each sub-array
        // represents a "match".  So for example, if the pointer is not near any split, then this will return
        // an empty array.  If it matches 3 splits (like the pointer is near a T-junction), then the outer array
        // will contain 3 sub-arrays.  Each sub-array represents a matching split.  So for example, the
        // following example layout code:
        //
        // const layout = {
        //   areTopLevelSplittersVertical: false,
    
        //   content: [
        //     "one",
        //     20,
        //     [ "two", 40, "three" ],
        //     70,
        //     "four"
        //   ]
        // };
        //
        // Would produce this layout of components (the 40, 20, and 70 represent what percent the splits are.
        // They would not be displayed):
        //
        //        40
        //     ┌─────────┐
        //     │   one   │
        //     │         │
        //   20├───┬─────┤
        //     │   │     │
        //     │two│three│
        //     │   │     │
        //   70├───┴─────┤
        //     │  four   │
        //     │         │
        //     └─────────┘
        //
        // The array identifier for the horizontal 20% split would be [1].  As it is element 1 of the content array.
        // The 70% split would be [3].  Since the vertical 40% split is nested within element 2, it's identifier
        // would be [2,1].  Though the outer edges are not specified in the array, they are still identified by this
        // function.  So for example, the horizontal line above "one" would be [-1].  The horizontal line below
        // "four" would be [5], the short vertical line to the left of two would be [2,-1], and the short vertical
        // line to the right of three would be [2,3].
        //
        // The "shallow" parameter tells this function how "deep" to look.  The meat of this function is recursive.
        // If shallow was true, then this method would return a split as soon as it finds one.  It would not
        // recursively call itself on the bordering subcomponents.  If shallow were true, it would.  So for example,
        // imagine the mouse were on the split right above the "r" in "four".  If shallow were true, then this
        // function would return [[3]] (a single match of split [3]).  This is invoked when moving splits as one
        // would only needs to move split [3].  If shallow were false, then it would return: [[2,2,1],[3]].  This
        // is invoked when copying splits.  If the user were to select that point and copy up, it would copy split
        // [2,2,1].  If they were to copy down, it would copy split [3].
        const findNearestSplit = (percentVector,shallow) => {
            return findNearestSplitRecursive(percentVector,layoutState.content,{x:reshapeMargin,y:reshapeMargin},layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical,shallow);
        }
    
        // This is the recursive method that does the work for the method above.
        const findNearestSplitRecursive = (percentVector,content,margin,isCurrentSplitterVertical,shallow) => {
            var valToTest;
            var marginToTest;
            if( isCurrentSplitterVertical ) {
                valToTest = percentVector.x;
                marginToTest = margin.x;
            } else {
                valToTest = percentVector.y;
                marginToTest = margin.y;
            }
    
            const isArray = Array.isArray(content);
            const length = isArray ? content.length : null;
    
            var foundIndex;
            var childCandidateIndices;
            if( testWithinMargin( valToTest, 0, marginToTest ) ) { // is at min edge
                foundIndex = -1;
                childCandidateIndices = isArray ? [ 0 ] : null;
            } else if( testWithinMargin( valToTest, 100, marginToTest ) ) { // is at max edge
                if( isArray ) {
                    foundIndex = length;
                    childCandidateIndices = [ length-1 ];
                } else {
                    foundIndex = 1;
                    childCandidateIndices = null;
                }
            } else { // is somewhere between
                if( isArray ) {
                    const searchResult = binarySearch(content,valToTest,marginToTest);
                    if( searchResult%2==0 ) {
                        // If it was a component and not a split
                        foundIndex = null;
                        childCandidateIndices = [ searchResult ];
                    } else {
                        // If it was a split
                        foundIndex = searchResult;
                        childCandidateIndices = [ foundIndex-1, foundIndex+1 ];
                    }
                } else {
                    foundIndex = null;
                    childCandidateIndices = null;
                }
            }
    
            var returnMe = [];
            if( shallow && foundIndex!=null ) {
                returnMe.push([foundIndex]);
            } else {
                if( isArray ) {
                    childCandidateIndices.forEach( childIndex => {
                        const minValue = childIndex===0 ? 0 : content[childIndex-1];
                        const maxValue = childIndex===length-1 ? length-1 : content[childIndex+1];
    
                        var subPercentVector = convertVector(minValue,maxValue,isCurrentSplitterVertical,percentVector);
                        var subMargin = convertMargin(minValue,maxValue,isCurrentSplitterVertical,margin);
    
                        var recurseArray = findNearestSplitRecursive(subPercentVector,content[childIndex],subMargin,!isCurrentSplitterVertical,shallow);
                        if( recurseArray.length>0 ) {
                            recurseArray.forEach( subArray => {
                                var myArray = [childIndex];
                                myArray = myArray.concat(subArray);
                                returnMe.push(myArray);
                            });
                        } else {
                            if( foundIndex!==null ) {
                                returnMe.push([foundIndex]);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    if( foundIndex!==null ) {
                        returnMe.push([foundIndex]);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return returnMe;
        }
    
        // Simply tests is a value is within a given margin
        const testWithinMargin = (one, two, margin) => Math.abs(one - two) <= margin;
    
        // Performs a binary search within a context array.  For a point to be only
        // a split, it must be within the reshapeMargin (either wide).  Otherwise,
        // this function returns the index of the component that the point resides
        // within. This function is not recursive nor knows anything about nested
        // arrays.  It only knows about whatever array it is passed.  This call would
        // be invoked again on a sub-array if necessary.  It is not passed a point
        // (x,y), but just a single value (x or y).
        const binarySearch = (content,testForMe,margin) => {
    
            var minIndex = -1;
            var maxIndex = content.length;
            var foundIndex = null;
            var currentIndex;
    
            while(minIndex+2<maxIndex) {
                currentIndex = (minIndex+maxIndex)/2;
                if( currentIndex%2===0 ) {
                    currentIndex--;
                }
                const currentValue = content[currentIndex];
                if( testWithinMargin( currentValue, testForMe, margin ) ) {
                    foundIndex = currentIndex;
                    break;
                } else if( testForMe > currentValue ) {
                    minIndex = currentIndex;
                } else {
                    maxIndex = currentIndex;
                }
            }
    
            if (foundIndex===null) {
                foundIndex = minIndex+1;
            }
    
            return foundIndex;
        }
    
        // At the top container level, 0% is the top/left corner and 100%
        // is on the bottom/right corner.  When recursively calculating for
        // nested components, the vector is converted to a percentage
        // coordinate that corresponds to child components.  For example,
        // in the layout below:
        //     ┌─────────┐
        //     │   one   │
        //     ├───┬─────┤
        //     │   │+    │
        //     │two│three│
        //     │   │     │
        //     └───┴─────┘
        // The point marked by "+" may about (50%,50%) in relation to
        // the outer most container, but only at (10%,20%) in relation to
        // child component "three".
        const convertVector = (minValue,maxValue,isVertical,vector) => {
            const convFunction = val => 100*(val-minValue)/(maxValue-minValue);
            var subVector;
            if( isVertical ) {
                subVector = {
                    x: convFunction(vector.x),
                    y: vector.y
                };
            } else {
                subVector = {
                    x: vector.x,
                    y: convFunction(vector.y)
                };
            }
            return subVector;
        }
    
        // Similarly, margins change for child components too.  If 1% corresponds
        // to 10 pixels overall. Yet 10 pixels may be 1.3% for component three below.
        //     ┌─────────┐
        //     │   one   │
        //     ├───┬─────┤
        //     │   │     │
        //     │two│three│
        //     │   │     │
        //     └───┴─────┘
        // We don't want the margins getting smaller as people hover over nested
        // components and splits.
        const convertMargin = (minValue,maxValue,isVertical,margin) => {
            const marginFunction = val => val*100/(maxValue-minValue);
            var subMargin;
            if( isVertical ) {
                subMargin = {
                    x: marginFunction(margin.x),
                    y: margin.y
                };
            } else {
                subMargin = {
                    x: margin.x,
                    y: marginFunction(margin.y)
                };
            }
            return subMargin;
        }
    
        // Just for debug printing.
        const arrayToStringRecursive = (a,str) => {
            if( Array.isArray(a) ) {
                str = str.concat("[");
                var first = true;
                a.forEach( e => {
                    if( first ) {
                        first = false;
                    } else {
                        str = str.concat(",");
                    }
                    str = arrayToStringRecursive(e,str);
                });
                str = str.concat("]");
            } else {
                str = str.concat(a);
            }
            //console.log("about to return str="+str);
            return str;
        }
    
        // Just for debug printing.
        const arrayToString = (a) => {
            return arrayToStringRecursive(a,"");
        }
    
        // Just for debug printing.
        const printArray = (label,a) => {
            console.log(`${label}=${arrayToString(a)}`);
        }
    
        // Just for debug printing.
        const pointToString = (p) => `(${p.x},${p.y})`;
    
        // Convenience function for determining if state is one of the copy states.
        const isCopyState = stateEnum =>
            stateEnum===StateEnum.ElgibleToCopy
            || stateEnum===StateEnum.AboutToCopy
    
        // Convenience function for setting state to None
        const setToNoneState = () => {
            setState( {
                stateEnum: StateEnum.None
            } );
        }
    
        // Convenience function for setting state to EligibleToMove.
        const setToElgibleToMoveState = (split) => {
            setState( {
                stateEnum: StateEnum.ElgibleToMove,
                split: split
            } );
        }
    
        // Convenience function for setting state to AboutToMove
        const setToAboutToMoveState = (split,pressSplitLocation,pressMouseLocation) => {
            setState( {
                stateEnum: StateEnum.AboutToMove,
                split: split,
                pressSplitLocation: pressSplitLocation,
                pressMouseLocation: pressMouseLocation
            } );
        }
    
        // Convenience function for setting state to Moving
        const setToMovingState = (split,pressSplitLocation,pressMouseLocation,currentMouseLocation) => {
            setState( {
                stateEnum: StateEnum.Moving,
                split: split,
                pressSplitLocation: pressSplitLocation,
                pressMouseLocation: pressMouseLocation,
                currentMouseLocation: currentMouseLocation
            } );
        }
    
        // Convenience function for setting state to EligibleToCopy
        const setToElgibleToCopyState = (split) => {
        
            setState( {
                stateEnum: StateEnum.ElgibleToCopy,
                split: split
            } );
        }
    
        // Convenience function for setting state to AboutToCopy
        const setToAboutToCopyState = (splits,pressLocation) => {
            setState( {
                stateEnum: StateEnum.AboutToCopy,
                splits: splits,
                pressLocation: pressLocation
            } );
        }
    
        // Function that evaluates the state of the mouse cursor, ctrl button, and mouse
        // button to determine what state this should be in.
        const determineState = (e) => {
            const stateEnum = state.stateEnum;
            const percent = eventToPercentVector(e);
            const nearSplit = findNearestSplit(percent,!isCopyState(stateEnum));
            const length = nearSplit.length;
    
            const isPressedNow = e.buttons &= 1;
            if( isPressedNow ) {
                if( stateEnum===StateEnum.None 
                        || stateEnum===StateEnum.ElgibleToCopy
                        || stateEnum===StateEnum.ElgibleToMove ) {
                    if(e.ctrlKey) {
                        if( length>0 && length<3 ) {
                            const nearSplits = findNearestSplit(percent,false);
                            setToAboutToCopyState(nearSplits,percent);
    
                        }
                    } else {
                        if( length>0 ) {
                            setToAboutToMoveState(nearSplit,getSplitLocation(nearSplit[0]),percent);
                        }
                    }
                } else if( stateEnum===StateEnum.AboutToCopy ) {
                    const nearSplits = findNearestSplit(percent,false);
                    if( JSON.stringify(nearSplits) !== JSON.stringify(state.splits) ) {
                        const isVertical = state.splits[0].length%2 === 1 ? layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical : !layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical;
                        var chosenIndex;
                        var loc;
                        if( isVertical ) {
                            chosenIndex = percent.x < state.pressLocation.x ? 0 : 1;
                            loc = percent.x;
                        } else {
                            chosenIndex = percent.y < state.pressLocation.y ? 0 : 1;
                            loc = percent.y;
                        }
                        var chosenSplit;
                        if(state.splits.length===1) {
                            // Left most split will only have 1 element but we want to treat it as the right/bottom most.
                            chosenSplit = state.splits[0];
                        } else {
                            chosenSplit = state.splits[chosenIndex];
                        }
                        insertSplit( chosenSplit, loc, chosenIndex===1 );
                        if(chosenIndex===1) {
                            chosenSplit[ chosenSplit.length-1 ]+=2;
                        }
                        setToMovingState(chosenSplit,loc,percent,percent);
              document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); //disable text select
                    }
    
                } else if( stateEnum===StateEnum.AboutToMove ) {
                    if( JSON.stringify(nearSplit) !== JSON.stringify(state.nearSplit) ) {
                        setToMovingState(state.split[0],state.pressSplitLocation,state.pressMouseLocation,percent);
              document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); //disable text select
                    }
                } else if( stateEnum===StateEnum.Moving ) {
                    setToMovingState(state.split,state.pressSplitLocation,state.pressMouseLocation,percent);
            document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); //disable text select
                }
            } else if(e.ctrlKey) {
                if( length>0 && length<3 ) {
                    setToElgibleToCopyState(nearSplit);
                } else {
                    setToNoneState();
                }
            } else if( length===0 ) {
                setToNoneState();
            } else {
                setToElgibleToMoveState(nearSplit);
            }
        }
    
        // Draws cursor based on current state
        const updateCursor = e => {
            const target = e.currentTarget;
        var cursorToUse;
        
    
    
            if( state.stateEnum===StateEnum.ElgibleToMove ) {
                var isVertical;
    
                if( layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical ) {
                    isVertical = true;
                } else {
                    isVertical = false;
                }
    
                if( state.split[0].length%2 === 0 ) {
                    isVertical = !isVertical;
                }
    
                if( isVertical ) {
                    cursorToUse = "col-resize";
                } else {
                    cursorToUse = "row-resize";
                }
          
            } else if( state.stateEnum===StateEnum.ElgibleToCopy ) {
         cursorToUse = "copy";
            } else {
                cursorToUse = "default";
            }
            target.style.cursor = cursorToUse;
        }
    
        // Generic function for deep copying the content array.  Used when
        // changing the content.
        const deepContentCopy = (content) => {
            if(Array.isArray(content)) {
                var ret=[];
                content.forEach( element => { ret.push( deepContentCopy(element) ); } );
                return ret;
            } else {
                return content;
            }
        }
    
        // Method for getting split location percentage.  The split parameter is
        // an array identifier (like [1,2,3]) and it's location percentage is returned.
        const getSplitLocation = split => {
            var current = layoutState.content;
            split.forEach( element => {
                current = current[element];
            } );
            return current;
        }
    
        // Method for setting split location percentage.  The split parameter is
        // an array identifier (like [1,2,3]) and the loc is a percentage (0-100)
        const setSplitLocation = (split,loc) => {
            var copy = deepContentCopy(layoutState.content);
            var copyLayoutState = {
                areTopLevelSplittersVertical: layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical,
                content: copy
            };
    
            var parent = copy;
            for( var i=0;i<split.length-1;i++) {
                parent = parent[ split[i] ];
            }
            const last = split[ split.length-1 ];
            parent[ last ] = loc
            setLayoutState(copyLayoutState);
        }
    
        // This returns the location of splits on either side of a given
        // index.  This is best shown with an example:
        //
        // percentage: 0%   25%   50%   75%   100%
        //             ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
        //             │ one │ two │three│four │
        //             └─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
        //     index: -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
        //
        // The min/max of distance 1 from index 2 would be 25% and 50%.
        // The min/max of distance 2 from index 3 would be 25% and 75%.
        //
        // It basically returns the value of the splits on each side of
        // from a given index, but is smart in that it returns 0% and
        // 100% rather than try to access an array out of bounds.
        const calcMinMax = (parent,index,distance) => {
            var minValue;
            var maxValue;
    
            if( index-distance<0 ) {
                minValue = 0;
            } else {
                minValue = parent[ index - distance ];
            }
    
            if( index+distance>=parent.length) {
                maxValue = 100;
            } else {
                maxValue = parent[ index + distance ];
            }
    
            return {
                minValue: minValue,
                maxValue: maxValue
            }
        }
    
        // Performs the move state action.
        const moveSplit = (movingState) => {
            var isVertical = layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical;
            var currentMouseLocation = movingState.currentMouseLocation;
    
            // This gets the parent of the split in question.
            const split = movingState.split;
            var parent = layoutState.content;
            for( var i=0;i<split.length-1;i++) {
                const component = split[i];
    
                const {minValue,maxValue} = calcMinMax(parent,component,1);
    
                currentMouseLocation = convertVector(minValue,maxValue,isVertical,currentMouseLocation);
                isVertical = !isVertical;
                parent = parent[ component ];
            }
    
            var loc = isVertical ? currentMouseLocation.x : currentMouseLocation.y;
    
            const splitIndex = split.length-1;
            const {minValue,maxValue} = calcMinMax(parent,split[splitIndex],2);
            if( loc+reshapeMargin>=maxValue ) {
                // The user moved the split beyond the edge of the next spit.  Delete it (and the component it contained).
                parent.splice( split[splitIndex], 2 );
                setToNoneState();
            } else if ( loc-reshapeMargin<=minValue ) {
                // The user moved the split beyond the edge of the previous spit.  Delete it (and the component it contained).
                parent.splice( split[splitIndex]-1, 2 );
                setToNoneState();
            } else {
                // Set new split location.
                setSplitLocation(split,loc);
            }
        }
    
        // Inserts a split before or after the provided split at given location.
        const insertSplit = (split, loc, isAfter) => {
            var copy = deepContentCopy(layoutState.content);
            if( !Array.isArray(copy) ) {
                copy = [copy];
            }
            var copyLayoutState = {
                areTopLevelSplittersVertical: layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical,
                content: copy
            };
    
            var parent = copy;
            for( var i=0;i<split.length-1;i++) {
                var child = parent[ split[i] ];
                if( !Array.isArray(child) ) {
                    child = [child];
                    parent[ split[i] ] = child;
                }
                parent = child;
            }
            const last = split[ split.length-1 ];
            if(isAfter) {
                parent.splice( last+1, 0, loc );
                parent.splice( last+1, 0, "chooser" );
            } else {
                parent.splice( last, 0, "chooser" );
                parent.splice( last, 0, loc );
            }
            setLayoutState(copyLayoutState);
        }
    
        // Handler for the mouse move event
        const mouseMoved = (e) => {
            determineState(e);
            updateCursor(e);
    
            if( state.stateEnum===StateEnum.Moving ) {
                moveSplit(state);
            }
        }
    
        // Handler for the mouse down event
        const mouseDown = (e) => {
            determineState(e);
            updateCursor(e);
        }
    
        // Handler for the mouse up event
        const mouseUp = (e) => {
            determineState(e);
            updateCursor(e);
        }
    
        // Generates DOM for browser to display.
        const generateDOM = layoutState => {
            return (
            <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                    tabIndex={0}
                    onMouseMove={mouseMoved}
                    onMouseDown={mouseDown}
                    onMouseUp={mouseUp}>
                {generateContent(layoutState.content,layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical)}
            </div>);
        }
    
        // Recursive function called by generateDOM.
        const generateContent = (layoutState,isCurrentSplitterVertical) => {
    
            var styleGenerator;
            if( isCurrentSplitterVertical ) {
                styleGenerator = percent => { return { height: "100%", width: percent+"%", overflow: "auto" } };
            } else {
                styleGenerator = percent => { return { height: percent+"%", width: "100%", overflow: "auto" } };
            }
    
            var content;
            if( Array.isArray(layoutState) ) {
                if( layoutState.length>0 ) {
                    var lastPercent=0;
                    var elements=[{
                        child: generateContent(layoutState[0],!isCurrentSplitterVertical)
                    }];
                    for(var i=1;i<layoutState.length;i++) {
                        var element = layoutState[i];
                        const elementPercent = element-lastPercent;
                        elements[elements.length-1].percent = elementPercent;
                        lastPercent += elementPercent;
                        i++;
                        if(i>=layoutState.length) {
                            throw "Expect content array to have odd number of elements.  Children name strings with splitter percentages between i="+i+" length="+layoutState.length+".";
                        }
                        elements.push( {
                            child: generateContent(layoutState[i],!isCurrentSplitterVertical)
                        });
                    }
    
                    elements[elements.length-1].percent = 100-lastPercent;
    
                    content =
                        <div style={{display:"flex",
                                flexDirection:isCurrentSplitterVertical ? "row" : "column",
                                width: "100%",
                                height: "100%",
                        }}>
                            {elements.map( (element,index) => (
                            <div key={index} style={styleGenerator(element.percent)}>
                                {element.child}
                            </div> ))}
                        </div>
                } else {
                    content = <p>no child!</p>;
                }
            } else {
                content = childMap[layoutState];
            }
    
            return content;
        }
    
        return generateDOM(layoutState);
    }
    
    export default BlenderSplitter;
```

```css
    .App-logo {
        height: 40vmin;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    @media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
        .App-logo {
            animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
        }
    }
    
    .App-header {
        /*min-height: 100vh;*/
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
        width: 600px;
        height: 500px;
        color: white;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .App-link {
        color: #61dafb;
    }
    
    @keyframes App-logo-spin {
        from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
    
    .blah {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .App {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .ctrl-button {
      background: white;
      color: #333;
      border: none;
      cursor: copy;
    }
    
    .ass {
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 20px;
    }
    
    #chooser {
      background-color: #535353;
    
    }
    
    #one {
        background-color: rgb(255, 143, 143);
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    #two {
        background-color: rgb(153, 255, 160);
    }
    
    #three {
        background-color: rgb(158, 158, 255);
    }
    
    #four {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 142);
    }
```

**I made a sandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-swartz-f9ho3j?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js

I have a button on the chooser panel and you can select 1 , 2, 3 or 4. Right now it just throws an alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
class GateKeeper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ input: event.target.value })
  }
  render() {
    let inputStyle = {
      border: '1px solid black'
    };
    // change code below this line

    // change code above this line
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Don't Type Too Much:</h3>
        <input
          type="text"
          style={inputStyle}
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But how would I implement this into my existing code?